# In Flutter, use key value for widget rather than indexed array

Tags: flutter, dart

I am creating a list/array of widgets that will be used for routes in flutter as below

```
final routeScreens = [
  const Login(),
  const LandingPage(), 
];

MaterialApp(
  routes: {
    RoutesPath.loginPath: (context) => routeScreens[0],
    Routes.landingPage: (context) => routeScreens[1],
  },
);
```

How do I change this from list to an object? As in I would like to access routeScreen['login'] rather than using the index.

I tried the below code, but it gives return type is not widget

```
final routeScreens = {
  'login' : const Login(),
  'landing' : const LandingPage(), 
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried specifying a generic type because it's otherwise `Map<dynamic,dynamic>`

```
final routeScreens = <String, Widget>{
  'login' : const Login(),
  'landing' : const LandingPage(), 
};
```

Comment: if this is used '''RoutesPath.loginPath: (context) => routeScreens['login']''' it gives error:  A value of type 'Widget?' can't be returned from a function with return type 'Widget' because 'Widget?' is nullable and 'Widget' isn't.

Comment: Ah, it's because of the Map itself, just put the `!` at the end when calling routeScreens like: `routeScreens['login']!`.